# Преобразование HEX UTF8 во float

Tags: c#

Существует ли более быстрый способ для перевода HEX UTF8 во float чем способ показанный ниже:

```
        byte[] freqArray = { 0x31, 0x31, 0x34, 0x38, 0x2E, 0x35, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30 };

        string freqs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(freqArray);

        float freq = float.Parse(freqs, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine(freq); //1148.5
```

Comment: Вы точно не путаете hex с двоичным представлением числа? вроде такого есть `BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00), 0);`

Comment: @nick_n_a вроде нет. BitConverter.ToSingle не работает для меня.

Comment: Если вы хотите заточить конкретно под форму xxxx.yyyy то можно преобразовать выражением вида `if (fa[i]==0x2E) freq =.... (fa[i-2]-0x30)*10  + (fa[i-1]-0x30) +  (fa[i+1]-0x30)*0.1  + (fa[i+2]-0x30)*0.01 ... ;` Это будет быстрее, потому что первое - не тратим мощьностя на преобразование в строку, второе - можно оптимизировать, и даже применить подобие "двоичного поиска" для 0x2E. Так же можно упростить задачу сделав преобразование не линейной формулой, а двумя циклами (один для целой части, второй для дробной, цикл чуть снизит быстродействие)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете `.NET Core 2.1+` и особо не хотите изобретать другие алгоритмы, то можно воспользоваться `Utf8Parser` из `System.Buffers.Text`:

```
var result = Utf8Parser.TryParse(freqArray, out float freq, out _);
if (!result)
    throw ...;

Console.WriteLine(freq);
```

Работает примерно в 2.2 раза быстрее (проверял на i5, Mac OS, .NET Core 3.1) и не создает лишних строк.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее быстрый вариант оказался следующим:

```
private static float HexSpanToFloat(Span<byte> span)
    {
        return (float)((span[0]&0xf)*1000+
                       (span[1]&0xf)*100+
                       (span[2]&0xf)*10+
                       (span[3]&0xf)+
                       (span[5]&0xf)*0.1+
                       (span[6]&0xf)*0.01+
                       (span[7]&0xf)*0.001+
                       (span[8]&0xf)*0.0001+
                       (span[9]&0xf)*0.00001+
                       (span[10]&0xf)*0.000001);
    }
```

С подсказки  nick_n_a

Comment: Вместо `byte[], int start, int length` используйте `Span<byte>`, мы не в 2005. Так же, возможно, это поможет вам избавиться от дополнительной аллокации на стадии получения/формирования массива с байтами

Comment: Я бы сказал даже `ReadOnlySpan`